# Bean property 'eraseCredentialsAfterAuthentication' is not writable or has an invalid setter method in GRAILS 2.0.4

Tags: grails, spring-security, grails-2.0

I have upgraded from grails 1.3.x to 2.0.4, It is not running.

```
  Caused by NotWritablePropertyException: Invalid property 'eraseCredentialsAfterAuthentication' of bean class [org.springframework.secur
ity.authentication.ProviderManager]: Bean property 'eraseCredentialsAfterAuthentication' is not writable or has an invalid setter metho
d. Does the parameter type of the setter match the return type of the getter?
->> 303 | innerRun in java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -
|   138 | run      in java.util.concurrent.FutureTask
|   886 | runTask  in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker
|   908 | run      in     ''
^   619 | run . .  in java.lang.Thread
```

I have `spring-security-core:1.2.7.3` plugin installed and i added `compile ':spring-security-core:1.2.7.3'` line in my plugin dependency.

I deleted the .grails directory also as [it says](http://grails.1312388.n4.nabble.com/Trying-to-upgrade-an-existing-project-from-grails-1-3-5-to-2-1-0-arrrrrg-td4637293.html).

What is the reason for this. How to resolve this issue,

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have an older version of one of the Spring Security jars. This property is set on the `org.springframework.security.authentication.ProviderManager` class which is in `spring-security-core-3.0.7.RELEASE.jar`. Running `grails war` and unzip the war file that's created in the target directory - you should see an older version of that jar in the WEB-INF/lib folder.

Are you using any other plugins that might bring in an older version of this jar?